# Creating a keyboard shortcut to go to a specific folder on Mac OS Finder

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

I use `⌘+SHIFT+G` in my routine on macOS and with `⌘+SHIFT+D` (go to user/desktop) or `⌘+ALT+L` (go to user/downloads) I can travel pretty fast.

But there are some folders that I'd like to go to quickly in the same manner that the desktop or downloads folder. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: There's no native way to do this. Best I could think of is Automator with an Applescript, set as a Service.

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. Quicksilver
2. BetterTouchTool
3. Apple Shortcuts App

### QuickSilver

I tend to use Quicksilver for this:

1. Open the quicksilver search
2. Start typing the folder (a few letters). Find the folder in the results. Right click -> "set default"

Then, typing this in the future automatically sets that as the first result.

### BetterTouchTool

You could also try BetterTouchTool to key map a shortcut directly. This is fairly straightforward.

### Apple Shortcuts

Somewhat confusing for me. This is the automation I ended up with. Then I trigger it by opening Siri Spotlight Search and typing the shortcut name

[image]